# Not sure why my variable is overwirting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm working with a MVC and am trying to pass a date through my URL.  I'd like the method to default to today's date if no date is provided in the URL.

```
    public ActionResult Date(string date)
    {
        DateTime searchDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        bool success = false;

        if(date != null)
        {
            success = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out searchDate);
        }

        List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();

        foreach (Article a in db.Articles)
        {
            if (a.PostedDateTSU.Value.Day == searchDate.Day && a.PostedDateTSU.Value.Month == searchDate.Month &&
                a.PostedDateTSU.Value.Year == searchDate.Year)
            {
                articles.Add(a);
            }
        }
        return View(articles);
    }
```

My problem is when I enter the url: "http://localhost:52159/Articles/Date/09-08-2016" the method is still defaulting to today's date.  Not sure where it's going wrong. I have a feeling it has to do with the TryParseExact().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the value of 'success' after this? Put a little debug point or message in there to see if it's even reaching TryParseExact().

Comment: If its a date, why are you using `string` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't think I could pass a viable DateTime format via URL without additional parsing.  Could I?

Comment: @WBT It's false as of the List<Article> line using the same URL listed above

Comment: Of course - the `DefaultModelBinder` will parse the the parameter to `DateTime` (assuming it matches the culture of your server, or you use ISO format - `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok I'll give that a spin

Comment: I assume also that you do have a specific route definition that accepts a parameter named `date`. If not, and you using the default route, it would need to be `public ActionResult Date(DateTime id)`

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted could ever default to _today's_ date. `TryParseExact()` will always set the `searchDate` value, so assuming you're calling it, you'll only ever get `DateTime.MinValue` (the default output value) or the value you're trying to parse. You'll only get today's date if that's what you are parsing (which, of course, was in fact the case yesterday, given the URL you're showing :) ).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Welp, I feel stupid.  I did not have a custom route definition...  My parameter was not named id.  That made the difference.  Thank you so much!

Comment: In any case, there may be better ways to approach this, but `TryParseExact()` does just that...it assumes the format you're passing matches the string exactly. If you're trying to parse the entire URL, then for the parse to fail is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was not sure if TryParseExact would still overwrite searchDate when the statement evaluated to false.  I believe it does not output anything when false.  Turned out I just needed to name my parameter "id" and now it is working.  Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: It sounds like you were able to get the MVC-specific feature to work, obviating the need for your parsing. Seems like that's ideal. That said: `out` _requires_ the declaring method to set the variable to _something_, and the method's parameter is considered uninitialized until it's been set (i.e. the method has no way to read the value you passed in). The method doesn't have a choice. The variable will always get set by the method, so you are guaranteed that whatever you set it to before is going to be overwritten, always.

Answer (score 1):

You need to route your parameter or access to the action like this http://localhost:52159/Articles/Date?date=09-08-2016"

Example in RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DateRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{date}",
            defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "Date", date = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

    }
```

Comment: That will not work (everything will now match the DateRoute and the Default route will never be hit). The DateRoute needs to be `url: "Articles/Date/{date}",` and `defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Date" }`